# Server connect to client without needing URL (because client connects first)

Tags: rust, grpc, rust-tokio, rust-tonic

In a scenario where the gRPC server doesn't know the URLs of clients in general, but clients know the URL of the (single) server, it would be useful to be able to *initiate connections to client endpoints from the server, once a client connects to us*.

It might be necessary to actually extract the URL from a connecting client and manually initiate the connection as usual from server-to-client (where server is client in the secondary connection). But there may be a way to connect which abstracts the URL, given that we already have a TCP connection from client to server and some object we could get a handle on.

I don't know which part of the `tonic` API this functionality would be contained in - if it exists - but it seems it should be possible in principle.

Edit: fwiw client and server will always be in the same network. So NAT considerations don't apply and we can assume any URL would be usable.

Comment: Why add tags at the beginning of the question? This is what we have, ah, tags for.

Comment: Unless client and server are in the same network it's unlikely to work. Over internet most devices are behind NAT routers that hide them from external connections. This is the very same problem that active-mode FTP stumbled upon in modern networks and why it was replaced by passive-mode. Alternative: Open a WebSocket connection from the client, leave it open and let the server talk back whenever it likes on the established connection.

Comment: Point taken about NAT and not being able to extract a usable URL for connecting clients in general, but we already have an established TCP connection - would it be possible to make use of it for a second gRPC connection / multiplex on it?

Comment: I don’t understand. gRPC is built on HTTP/2 which, in turn, is built on TCP. HTTP is a _client-server_ protocol, so, the communication must be initiated by a client. If the server already has a connection established with some client, there’s nothing to establish anymore, it can just use that. If it doesn’t have a connection with a client, it can’t use gRPC to send data to the client. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't think that clients usually have a `URL` but only an `IP` address, this might be always the same in a closed network, but change if `IPv4` and in public internet. Still, some providers never support `IPv6` yet, so this is just a technical bottleneck.

Comment: It would be sufficient to be able to extract the IP from the existing TCP connection, intending to establish a new independent connection where the server-client roles are reversed. Is there a way to extract the IP from the TCP connection using tonic?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be sufficient. The new connection most certainly has different ports, and thus the NAT router would block it. There are techniques that achieve similar things to what you have in mind, called [hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)), but they are quite complicated and probably out of scope for this question.

Comment: The server doesn't have to connect to the client. The client connects to the server, and the server accepts the connection. That gives both ends a full-duplex connection to the other end. No second connection is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you mean. I don't think you can make the server open a new and separate connection to the client without adding a lot of complexity but if you want the server to communicate to client endpoints, once they have connected, you could use [Bidirectional Streaming RPC](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/#bidirectional-streaming-rpc). This allows the server to send messages back to the client over that same connection, without needing the client's URL/IP or initiating a new connection. This effectively allows your gRPC server to "push" data to connected clients.

In `tonic` you define `rpc` methods inside your service definition, and the `stream` keyword indicates that multiple messages can be sent e.g.

```
// Accepts a stream of RouteNotes sent while a route is being traversed,
// while receiving other RouteNotes (e.g. from other users).
rpc RouteChat(stream RouteNote) returns (stream RouteNote) {}
```

There are some basic examples [here](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/blob/master/examples/routeguide-tutorial.md#bidirectional-streaming-rpc).